# Number of records returned from team.accessLogs API too large for page and count constraints?

Tags: slack-api

API in question: https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs

The maximum page is 100 and the maximum records per page(count) is 1000 so total 100,000 records could potentially be returned.  Since there is no way to limit the starting date for the accessLog, the results will continue to grow as more unique user/IP/useragent combinations are used until it reaches the limit at which point it wouldn't be possible to return all records. Is this correct?

Also, the documentation does not specify how the results are ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mentioned correctly that typically you can fetch 100,000 records.

But there is a way to limit the starting date.

`before` argument in api lets you set the time before which you want the records.

  https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs#arg_before

The records are **fetched in reverse chronological order** i.e. latest record first, 
and by default, the value of `before` argument is 'now'.

After fetching first 100,000 records,

 set `before` argument value as "date_last" value from the last record.

*(keep in mind that `before` argument is inclusive of the value provided, 
therefore the last record will be repeated. 
To avoid it you can reduce "date_last" value by 1 )*

Comment: `before` is simply a filter on the date_last value which is used to sort the result in reverse chronological order, not actually a way to go back to see logs from a prior point in time?   

For example, if I wanted to see if a given user/ip/useragent logged in between 2021-07-01 and 2021-07-07, I couldn't set the `before` to 2021-07-07 then iterate through to find that record and check `date_last` to see if it is after 2021-07-01 because it is returning current state values meaning the `date_last` for that record could be 2021-07-08 so wouldn't be returned at all with that `before` value.

Comment: As per my POC, this was not the case. Can you please test and comeback with some screenshots?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  That matches my findings.  The documentation makes it sound as if you are going back to a point in time: "Need to time travel? Set the before parameter to the oldest timestamp returned by the method to browse access logs from further back in time."

Comment: Glad that it helps. Can you please mark the answer as accepted, if it satisfies your question?